# How do i improve my custom pagination?

Tags: pagination

So this is my current pagination
Currently i am working with total of 6 pages so it shows
1 2 3 .. 5 6 (in the image below)
[image: This is the image]
5 and 6 being the second last and last 
But when i reach the number 5 it still shows number 5 and 6 and again when i am at page number 4 and i can see page number 5 still shows 5 and 6 as per my approach (in the image below)

[image: This is the image]

But i managed to hide the 5 and 6 when i am in the last page like this below
[image: This is the image]

But i dont think this is a good approach as per mine. My requirement is that i want a list of pagination and it should display the last and second last and when i am at the last pages it should show first and second. How can i do that?
Here's my current code

```php
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 2)
{
    $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;
    global $paged;
    if(empty($paged)) 
        $paged = 1;
    if($pages == '')
    {
        global $wp_query;
        $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        if(!$pages)
            $pages = 1;
    }
if(1 != $pages)
{
echo "<div class='paginations'>";
    echo "<nav class='page-navigation'>";
    echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
    $first_page = $paged -1;
    $last_page = $pages - $paged;
    $second_last = $pages - 1;  
        if($first_page)
            echo "<li class='page-item'><a aria-current='page' class='page-numbers page-link prev' href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>PREVIOUS</a></li>";

            for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
            {
                if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
                    {
                        echo ($paged == $i)? "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-numbers page-link current'>".$i."</a></li>" : "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-numbers page-link' href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."'>".$i."</a></li>";
                    }
            }
            if(!($last_page == 0)){
                if($pages > 5){
                        echo"<li class='page-item'><a class='page-numbers page-link'>..</a></li>";
                        echo"<li class='page-item'><a class='page-numbers page-link' href='".get_pagenum_link($second_last)."'>$second_last</a></li>";
                        echo"<li class='page-item'><a class='page-numbers page-link' href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>$pages</a></li>";
                    }
            }

            if(!($last_page == 0)){
                echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='next page-numbers page-link' href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>NEXT</a></li>";
            }


        echo "</ul></nav></div>";
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the positive comment. :D I hope i will

Comment: What you're trying is possible with `paginate_links()`. Is there are reason you're trying to do this yourself?

Comment: yeah Jacob so i can use ajax later